# How to use NSNumberFormatter to insert blank space to NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to write a `UITextField` that can auto format a number to bank number.

For example: Input `1234567890098765` will be automatically displayed as `1234 5678 9009 8765`.

I'll use `textFieldDelegate` to do it, but I don't know how to use `NSNumberFormatter`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `NSNumberFormatter` is simple.

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:1234567890098765];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
// [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"\u00a0"];
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

I deliberately commented the line that sets the formatter's grouping separator as it may be better to use the default one, which is provided by the user's locale (e.g. `,` in the USA, `.` in Germany and `'` in Switzerland). Also please note that iOS doesn't use a space as a separator but a non-breaking space (`U+00A0`).

Comment: Thank you very much,you're right.i need format normal number to bank id.so i need blank space separator it.I can use setGroupingSeparator:@" " do it.Thank you!you are good one!

Comment: Please note, that if you're formatting a _currency_, you should set `currencyGroupingSeparator` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

   NSString *text = [textField text];

    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789\b"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[characterSet invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    }

    text = [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSString *newString = @"";
    while (text.length > 0) {
        NSString *subString = [text substringToIndex:MIN(text.length, 4)];
        newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:subString];
        if (subString.length == 4) {
            newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
        }
        text = [text substringFromIndex:MIN(text.length, 4)];
    }

    newString = [newString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[characterSet invertedSet]];

    if (newString.length >= 20) {
        return NO;
    }

    [textField setText:newString];

    return NO;
    }
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

i have a c++ solution, maybe you can change your string to cstring and then change back

```
char s[50]={'\0'},ch[99]={'\0'};
int i,j,k,len;
printf("input a string:\n");
scanf("%s",s);
len=strlen(s);
k=0;
for(i=0;i<len;i+=4)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        *(ch+k)=*(s+i+j);
        k++;

    }
        *(ch+k)=' ';
        k++;
}
printf("%s\n",ch);
```